# Java ScriptEngine-Like step by step execution

Tags: java, eval

Is there a way to execute a code like the ScriptEngine does, but step by step ?

For exemple :

```
if (contact(player,self)){
    callCinematics("forest.png", "face1.png","SALUT!");
    teleport("test",0,5,5);
} else {
    print("A");
}
```

I want to execute this code step by step, when I call my function eval(), first, it will check the condition, and wait for the second call.
If the first call return true, the second call eval the "callCinematics(...);", or "print("A");" if the first call return false.
If the first call return false, the third call of eval will do nothing, until I call another function that restart all the call.

I don't know if i'm very understandable ^^'.

Comment: I search on Internet, and Coroutines could be a way.
But i don't find anything about Coroutines in Java, or it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want that? Do you want to create something like an interactive script engine?